# Select only the path component of url (similar to command + L)

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, google-chrome-extensions

Is there a way to select only the path component of an url, similar to how command + L select the entire url?

> domain.com/[**my/awesome/path**]

*I want to select only the section in brackets.*

Comment: There are a couple of extensions that copy the whole URL to the clipboard. I will try to fork one and see if I can modify it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update:* The extension below was updated and renamed to [Template](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dcjnfaoifoefmnbhhlbppaebgnccfddf) which seems to provide what you were looking for.

---

I forked NeoCotic's [URL-Copy Chrome extension](https://github.com/neocotic/URL-Copy) and reprogrammed it to add another option.

It now has the option to **just copy the path**:

[image]

... which does exactly what you need. So, for example, `http://superuser.com/questions/276362/` is copied as `questions/276362/`.

In order to install it, you must

- [**download the prebuilt ZIP**](https://github.com/downloads/slhck/URL-Copy/URL-Copy.zip) file and unzip it somewhere
- Go to the *Wrench menu - Tools - Extensions*
- Click the *Developer* sign in the upper right corner
- Click *Load unpacked extension...* and select the unzipped folder:

[image]

Et voila! It's still far from perfect, but I'll contact the developer.

Comment: why don't you just submit it to chrome web store?

Comment: @crucified soul Because **1)** it's not my own work and already released as a Chrome extension **2)** it's not fully implemented (icons and options missing) and **3)** I contacted the developers to integrate it into their extension if they like

Comment: Excellent, that is some impressive effort for an answer! :)

Comment: No problem, I was bored at work haha :)

Comment: I realize that this post is old but I just stumbled across it and, as the developer of URL Copy, I wanted to let you know that today it is known as Template and does so much more than it used to and is highly customizable but maintains the simplicity of the original extension. I was pleasantly surprised to find this answer and hope you'll check out Template in the [Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dcjnfaoifoefmnbhhlbppaebgnccfddf) or [GitHub](https://github.com/neocotic/template), if you prefer. **P.S.** You never did get in touch ;)

Comment: @Alasdair I did, on April 28, and you replied on May, 9th ;) — So does it do what the OP wanted here?

Comment: Apologies and well cited :) Template can do exactly what the OP wanted. He simply needs to create a new Template (via the Options page) with the contents `{path}`. It's that easy.