# Extension to auto copy URL

Tags: browser-addons, url

If I want to copy URL of current web page i have select the address from address bar and press "Ctrl + C". But is there any way, if no text is selected on a web page, when I press "Ctrl + C", it will copy URL of current place to clipboard. any firefox, chrome extensions or Greasemonkey script will do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of Chrome Extensions, the one I found quite good is [Template](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dcjnfaoifoefmnbhhlbppaebgnccfddf?hl=en). In order to copy the URL, you just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> on a Mac.

[image]

It's also [available on GitHub](https://github.com/neocotic/template).

It's a bit older, but you have probably seen this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/276362/select-only-the-path-component-of-url-similar-to-command-l/276423#276423) where I posted a customized version it that is able to just copy the path after the domain, too.

Comment: Anything for firefx?

Comment: Dunno, I haven't used FF since it came out years ago :D I guess you will [find some](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/search/?q=url+copy&cat=all&x=0&y=0)...

Comment: I realize that this post is old but I just stumbled across it and, as the developer of URL Copy, I wanted to let you know that today it is known as Template and does so much more than it used to and is highly customizable but maintains the simplicity of the original extension. I was pleasantly surprised to find this answer and hope you'll check out Template in the [Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dcjnfaoifoefmnbhhlbppaebgnccfddf) or [GitHub](https://github.com/neocotic/template), if you prefer.

Comment: @Alasdair Great, thanks for the update — I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: on firefox open url ... about:config  ... then give value of true to setting ... 
  browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll   .... then upon a single click to url it will copy url into clipboard ... perfect ! ... if only chrome was this easy

Answer (score 0):

Found a Great extension for chrome. It can copy /paste multiple urls too at one go.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-all-urls/djdmadneanknadilpjiknlnanaolmbfk?hl=en