# What is the opposite command to `CTRL + L` in a browser?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, browser, shortcuts, url

In most browsers (like Chrome, which I use) `CTRL + L` will take you to the address bar. Is there a shortcut for going back to where you were before clicking `CTRL + L`?

Example.

- I am writing a message.
- I click `CTRL + L` to go to the address bar and copy part of the current URL.
- I click `XXX` to return to the message that I am writing and paste the URL.
- I happily go on with my life (without ever taking my hands of the keyboard)

---

[Using Template](https://superuser.com/questions/277906/extension-to-auto-copy-url) is not what I want.

Comment: Yes. It is the same

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While in the Chrome address bar, press <kbd>F6</kbd> (up to 3 times) to return. Or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd>

For further reading about useful keyboard shortcuts see the official documentation: [Chrome keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179).

Comment: And this isn't just Chrome. It is a convention in Microsoft Windows desktop applications that F6 moves keyboard focus between key GUI parts. For instance, F6 works in Microsoft Word (and all other Office applications), Windows Explorer, the Registry Editor, most web browsers, and frankly all well-behaved Windows applications.

Comment: Pressing F6 in a new tab puts the keyboard focus on the bookmarks. I miss this feature quite a bit after switching to Firefox.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work on macOs

Comment: I would like to put an emphasis on @jmm. This does not work on Macbook M1 running macOS Monterey 12.5.

Answer (score 0):

There's ALT+D for achieving just what you want.

Comment: No, Alt-d is the same as Ctrl-l -- Toke Faurby wanted the opposite (go back to the page / form field)